# Want to test the calling of a specific method created by a factory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I am trying to write an integration test that does something like this.

- Create instance of class in setUp method of test using `ModelClass::factory([$params])` rather than a constructor
- Call some methods on this class that cause various things to happen
- Event will get fired at some point
- Event is listened for, event listener will call a method on the same object that produced the event.
- Exactly which method will be called (and params) depends on some logic inside the class (which is mostly what I'm trying to test).
- Method itself doesn't do anything (at the moment), but I want to know that is was called. Functionality will probably be implemented by a subclass at some point in the future by someone else.

So I want to assert that this method was called at some point during the test, and test which parameters were passed into it. At the moment I've managed to mock out the event itself to check that this was fired, but I can only test that the method was called manually (by putting a `dd()` into it). I can't seem to find a way to do this without mocking out the entire object (which would defeat the purpose of the test, because at that point I'm just testing the mock).

I know you can do "**partial**" mocks and maybe that's what I need, but that doesn't seem to play well with the `::factory([$params])` style of constructor.

I included this as answer because I can't edit my original.

```
<?php
    // The test itself

    protected function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->item = Item::factory()->createOne([
            "name" => "testing name",
            // Some other attributes
        ]);
    }

    public function test_the_thing() : void
    {
        $this->item->doSomeWork();
        $this->assertShouldHaveBeenCalled($item, "someMethod") // I want something like this
    }

    // Then a trait attached to the item class that looks like this

    public static function bootItemTrait(): void
    {
        Event::listen(function(MyCustomEvent $event) {
            if(method_exists($event->item,"someMethod") && some_other_conditions()) {
                $event->item->someMethod();
            }
        });
    }

    public function doSomeWork() : void {
        $result = doSomeComplicatedThings()
        MyCustomEvent::dispatch($this,$result);
    }

    // My custom event is just a basic event with this constructor

    public function __construct($item, $result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->item = $item;
    }
```

Comment: You need to include some boilerplate code or an made out example so we have some code to reproduce your problem. This is possible without a doubt :)

Comment: I just added some example code that is simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the joyful world of mocking, may i be your guide. You want to mock the call and take it from there, the problem is dependency injection and mocking `Laravel` models is not easy and is not recommended.

To combat this do a wrapper class for your call, this will allow you to overwrite your wrapper in the `Laravel` container. So where you `->doWork();`. You could do something similar to this. Important to know, when using dependency injection, never use the keyword `new`. Instead use `app(YourClass::class);`, `resolve(YourClass::class);` or use constructor/handle injection. In this case, i use the `resolve()` approach.

```
class YourModel extends Model {

    public function doWork()
    {
        /** @var DoWorkService $doWorkService */
        $doWorkService = resolve(DoWorkService::class);

        $doWorkService->doWork(1, "2");
    }
}
```

In this thought up example, i made a empty shell of a class to prove the point.

```
namespace App\Services;

class DoWorkService
{
    public function doWork($param1, $param2) {
        throw new \Exception('This is mocked and should not be called');
    }
}
```

Now in your testing class you can use the Mocking helpers `Laravel` provides. This examples require `doWork()` method to be called once, with the parameters `1, "2"` and returns `true` in this case.

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\DoWorkService;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Tests\TestCase;

class DoWorkTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testDoWork()
    {
        $yourModel = // create your model with the factory;

        $mock = $this->mock(DoWorkService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('doWork')
                ->once()
                ->with(1, "2")
                ->andReturn(true);
        });

        $yourModel->doWork();
    }
}
```

This is tested on my local project, so you should be set to implement something similar.