# Laravel8 - Mocking methods from factory relationship models

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

I am trying to test a specific part of my code, but some dependencies of a Model class make this test very difficult to perform. If those dependencies were on a class that is injected, I could easily mock the class. Is it possible to do something similar when it comes from a database relationship from a factory? I am converting the idea to the example in Laravel's documentation, to try to make it easier to exemplify :

```
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;

$user = User::factory()
            ->has(Post::factory()->count(3))
            ->create();
```

Let's say that I am testing a controller that will create comments for posts of an user. I'll use a factory to create the user and post and perform a test post call to the route /api/comments, this post has the fields post_id (int) and comment (text).
However, the Comments controller will call a method Post::canAddComment(), that will perform a lot of verifications to validate if the comment can be created. All those validations are out of the scope of my test.

Is it possible to use a Mock of the Post model class, so I can make, for example:

```
$postMock->shouldReceive('canAddComment')->once()->andReturn(true);
```

So that I don't need to be creating a whole scenario to be able to do the test?

Possible solution:

Extend the Post class, for tests only:

```
class PostThatAlwaysAllowsComments extends Post
{
    public function canAddComment() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then in the tests:

```
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;

$user = User::factory()
            ->has(PostThatAlwaysAllowsComments::factory()->count(3))
            ->create();
```

Comment: Can you include the canAddComment() it seems like it is static and there is no good way to mock static functions. Normally i would not care about the side effects of canAddComment and assert what you are testing, what is breaking? if external api etc. why not just mock that

Comment: It’s not static.. what I am testing depends on the result of this function. Of course it’s not about Posts and Comments, but it’s a validation function that does not goes to an external API, but it will need another 5 factories to create the proper scenario. I ended up creating this scenario and tests are working, but the test got too complex and the validation feature itself is being tested already in it’s own tests... If there’s no other better option, maybe I should try to break this code into smaller testable pieces ..

Comment: There is options but i need some example code to make a suggestion on how to do it :P Post::canAddComment() is a static call btw

Comment: My bad, I didn’t write properly.. I just wanted to write that canAddComment() is a method from Post class :D

Comment: I am not allowed to put here the real code, sorry… But if this helps, everything is done inside the same class (Post in the example), everything is SQL and business logic. One idea that just occurred me is to create a class that extends the model Post, changing what I need, and create a factory for it. The downside of this approach is that will end up with test classes inside the codebase to be tested…

Comment: I had this answer recently, isn't that the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69086615/want-to-test-the-calling-of-a-specific-method-created-by-a-factory-in-laravel/69128752#69128752 another time you can make your own example that explains the same :)

Comment: Yes!! Exactly! It's about the same problem! I missed that question completely! What you suggested is the ideal, my model grew too big and the class is doing way more than it should. Sending it to a a Service class as in your example would be the cleanest solution. I updated my post to add what I wanted to say. But definitely, using another class is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Ok cant flag your question as duplicate as the other question is not answered, will write up a similar answer when i get the time :)

Comment: I wrote up the answer, hope it helps if you have questions or trouble with the mocking i'm happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Laravel`, mocking models is not really a standard or neither convenient. Most of the times, you arrange the data and let's model do what models does. In your case you can utilise a wrapper / proxy aproach, to easiler be able to mock your calls. This will also act as the entry point for mocking, as you need a class in the container to be mocked.

```
class PostThatAlwaysAllowsComments extends Post
{
    public function canAddComment() {
        resolve(CommentService::class)->comment($this);
    }
}
```

There is used resolve as to fetch the service from the container, as the `new` keyword will not work.

Now using `Laravels` mock syntaxic sugar, you can mock the underlying service and avoid triggering the code you do not care about and asserting it is actually called.

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\CommentService;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Tests\TestCase;

class PostAddComentTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testDoWork()
    {
        $post = // create your model with the factory;

        $mock = $this->mock(CommentService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('comment')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn(true);
        });

        // call api or method
    }
}
```